# Syn get flat token stream

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

For the sake of this example: I want to write a proc macro attribute which modifies all number literals in a function body.

I have a `syn::Block` from a `syn::FnItem`. I want to map all over the tokens in the block and change literals. I currently have:

```rust
let token_stream = func
    .block
    .to_token_stream()
    .into_iter()
    .map(|token| ...)

func.block = Box::new(syn::parse2::<Block>(token_stream.collect()).unwrap());
```

The problem is `to_token_stream` from `Quote::ToTokens` returns a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` and its `into_iter` item is `proc_macro2::TokenTree` which is a nested representation of the tokens.

So for the block representing `2 + (3 + 4)`

The iterator is over the following single item:

```
Group {
    delimiter: Brace,
    stream: TokenStream [
        Literal {
            kind: Integer,
            symbol: "2",
            suffix: None,
            span: #0 bytes(209..210),
        },
        Punct {
            ch: '+',
            spacing: Alone,
            span: #0 bytes(211..212),
        },
        Group {
            delimiter: Parenthesis,
            stream: TokenStream [
                Literal {
                    kind: Integer,
                    symbol: "3",
                    suffix: None,
                    span: #0 bytes(214..215),
                },
                Punct {
                    ch: '+',
                    spacing: Alone,
                    span: #0 bytes(216..217),
                },
                Literal {
                    kind: Integer,
                    symbol: "4",
                    suffix: None,
                    span: #0 bytes(218..219),
                },
            ],
            span: #0 bytes(213..220),
        },
    ],
    span: #0 bytes(203..222),
}
```

Where the tokens are deeply nested in the structure.

I need a flat representation that would look like:

```rust
Literal("2")
Plus
ParenthesisOpen
Literal("3")
Plus
Literal("4")
ParenthesisClose
```

Is this possible? I could write my own `flat_map` thinh to go before the `map` to make it work but that is a lot of work. Does syn expose anything to do this? Maybe I should not parse it into a `syn::Block` before I do the transform...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that syn has a [mutable visiting module](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.74/syn/visit_mut/index.html). Rather than touching the token stream you can use a recursive visitor like so:

```rust
use syn::{visit_mut::{self, VisitMut}, LitInt};

struct MyNumberLiteralModifier;

impl VisitMut for MyNumberLiteralModifier {
    fn visit_lit_int_mut(&mut self, node: &mut LitInt) {
        *node = LitInt::new("10", node.span());   
    }
}

MyNumberLiteralModifier.walk_block(&mut my_block);
```

To do so `"visit-mut"` feature must be enabled for syn